# Python, Configure mod_wsgi with Flask application on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, apache2, flask, mod-wsgi

Okay I most be really bad at searching or a little slow. Anyways, after trying to setup `mod_wsgi` with my environment I have hit a wall.

I have tried the following tutorial. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/ But I find it to be confusing and unclear for a python newbie such as myself. I have also tried working through countless fragmented tutorials with now luck.

**This is what I have so far: (*windows 7 os*)**

1. Python 3.3 32bit installed and working
2. WAMP 32bit running Apache 2.4
3. My flask app running on localhost:5000 or `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

   Note: I have installed `mod_wsgi` in apache and that is working.

**My app is structured as follows:**

C:\Users\username\Documents\cms\app

```
app
  static
     script.js
     dbtest.py <--I am loading dbtest.py into home.html page
  templates
     home.html
  routes.py
  routes.wsgi
```

**My Virtual Host Script:**

My virtual host script is located here:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**And my script:**

```
Listen 5000

<VirtualHost http://127.0.0.1:5000>
    ServerName wsgihost
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:\Users\username\Documents\cms\app\routes.wsgi
        <Directory C:\Users\username\Documents\cms\app\>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**The Problem:**

So the problem here is a few things:

Firstly, I don't know how to test if this is working. I am under the assumption that (*if running properly*) I would see my db request via my ajax call. Instead what I see is the entire script.

Secondly, I am not entirely certain my virtualhost script is in the right spot for appache. And it probably isn't wrote right.

I have also tried the command `python routes.wsgi` Is this the proper way to test if wsgi is running?

I know I have a lot going on here and I appreciate the help of anyone who is willing to take the time to help me work through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a question for ServerFault or SuperUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a VirtualHost if nothing else is running on that Apache. Because you have set ServerName to 'wsgihost', it will only send requests to your Flask app if using the URL `http://wsgihost` and if wsgihost isn't a valid host name that maps to your machine, it will not work.